# consulta en mongo

Tags: mongodb, colecciones

Estoy intentando generar una consulta donde necesito que me muestre unos datos que son externos y los introduzca dentro de unas variables que son `zurich` y `previsora`, pero solo toma `zurich` mas no `previsora`. Lo intenté con `switch case` pero tampoco.
¿Será que hay alguna forma de acomodar todo de acuerdo a los parámetros que se encuentran en la consulta y filtrarlos de forma que me muestre los que son de `zurich` y los que son de `previsora`?

```
{
    "collection": "TrazaMensajeria",
    "aggregate": [
        {
            "$group": {"_id": {
                "usuario": "$usuario",
                "empresa": "$empresa",
                "canal": "$canal",
                "mes": {"$substr": ["$fecha",5,2]},
                "año": {"$substr": ["$fecha",2,2]}},
                "cantidad": {"$sum": 1}}
        },
        {
            "$project":
            {
            "_id": 0,
            "canal": "$_id.canal",
            "año": { "$concat": [ "20","$_id.año"]},
            "mes": "$_id.mes",
            "usuario": "$_id.usuario",
            "empresa":"$_id.empresa",
            "summary":
            {
                "$switch":
                {
                    "branches":[
                        {
                            "case": { "$and" : [
                                { "$or": [ {"$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$_id.usuario", 0, 2 ] }, "CC" ]} ,
                                                            {"$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$_id.usuario", 0, 2 ] }, "CE" ]}] },
                                                            {"empresa":"900846964"}
                                                            ] },
                            "then": "Zurich"
                            },
                            {
                            "case": { "$and" : [
                                { "$or": [ {"$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$_id.usuario", 0, 2 ] }, "CC" ]} ,
                                                            {"$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$_id.usuario", 0, 2 ] }, "CE" ]}] },
                                                            {"empresa":"860002400"}
                                                            ] },
                            "then": "Previsora"
                                    }
                        ],
                        "default": "$_id.usuario"
                }
                },
                "cantidad": "$_id.cantidad"
            }
        }
    ],
    "options": {
        "cursor": {
            "batchSize": 50
        },
        "allowDiskUse": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Como mejora a tu pregunta: ¿podrías darle un título más específico? Será de utilidad tanto para quienes quieran ayudarte, como para otros usuarios con el mismo problema que el tuyo, más adelante.

Comment: Hace falta ver un ejemplo de documento almacenado y de la salida esperada. Con el código de agregación que expones es difícil darse una idea a simple vista de lo que deseas lograr. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo necesario. Saludos